# Using togglebutton for RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

Say I want to use RowDetailsTemplate in my WPF.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <data:DataGrid x:Name="grdVwDetails" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed">
        <data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <data:DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Project}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                </data:DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="+" Click="HandleExpandCollapseForRow"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="EmployeeID" Binding="{Binding EmpID}"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

In code behind I use event to change the button appearance.

```
 private void HandleExpandCollapseForRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button expandCollapseButton = (Button)sender;
        DataGridRow selectedRow = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(expandCollapseButton);

        if (null != expandCollapseButton && "+" == expandCollapseButton.Content.ToString())
        {
            selectedRow.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            expandCollapseButton.Content = "-";
        }
        else
        {
            selectedRow.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            expandCollapseButton.Content = "+";
        }

    }
```

It seems work. My question is that I don't want to use +/- for button. I want to use different image for expand/collapse.
 And do it should be done in xaml instead of code behind.

The entire project can be found at http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/Silverlight/Collapse-RowDetailstemplate-on-clicking-again.aspx

That is for Silverlight, I use it for WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the `Button` in the `DataTemplate` with a `ToggleButton` with a custom template:

```
<ToggleButton Width="50" Height="50">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Image x:Name="img" Source="plus.png" />
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="minus.png" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```